# Make User defined field conditionally required by Branch in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, user-defined-fields

I am new Acumatica development. I added a user defined field in Acumatica. I want to make the field required based on the branch.
Please can you assist?

I have seen a few articles on making a field conditionally required, but I cannot find or edit the attributs for a User defined field.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a user defined field conditionally required depending on the current logged in branch. You will need to create an extension field in the code and put a PXUIRequired attribute on it, and define wheren it will be required.